# Django rest framework abstract model/serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a class Contact and 2 subclasses: Person, Company.

In my API, I'm trying to make a list with both companies and persons with the specialized fields filled, but I'm getting only the Contact's fields with this code.

```
class Contact(EntityBase):
    #base contact fields

class Company(Contact):
    #Company fields

class Person(Contact):
    #person fields
```

Serializers:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #all fields (base and specialized) specified


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #all fields (base and specialized) specified

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact

    def to_native(self, obj):
        #polymorphic serialzer
        if isinstance(obj, Person):
            return PersonSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_native(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, Person):
            return PersonSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_native(obj)
```

and View:

```
class ContactViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
```

With all this code, I get everything ok, but not the specialized fields. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: Where do you use your `PersonSerializer`?

Comment: I use it on ContactSerializer method to_native, but I think this part of the code is not being reached.

Comment: Yes, because your `obj` in `to_native` will always be a `Contact` model.

Comment: Before this, I was using django-polymorphic model but it didn't work too

Comment: Why don't you use your `PersonSerializer` or `CompanySerializer` directly?

Comment: I need company and person to be returned in the same view! I couldn't see any other way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93823/discussion-between-tiago-framesqui-and-reto-aebersold).

Comment: try using nested serializers .Follow official django-rest documentation for this.